# Dispatch Action in Unit Test that Invokes Subscribe in Component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ngrx

### Dispatching an Action that's subscribed to in a Component

I have an Angular 15 project and in various components I subscribe to particular events. I'm trying to dispatch a subscribed to Action in my unit test to validate certain effects happen in the component.

##### Action Listener in Component

```js
this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(
        loadProcessorsForGroupSuccess,
        loadProcessorsForGroupFailure
      )
    ).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('update success')
      this.spinner.hide('processing')
    });
```

##### Jest Unit Test

```js
beforeAll(() =>
  MockBuilder(ProcessingComponent, AppModule)
    .provide(provideMockStore({
      initialState,
      selectors: [ ...my selector definitions ]
    }))
    .provide(provideMockActions(() => actions$))
    .mock(NgxSpinnerService, {
      show: jest.fn(),
      hide: jest.fn()
    })
    .mock(NgbOffcanvas)
    .mock(ProcessorsService)
    .keep(UpperCasePipe)
  );
)
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = MockRender(ProcessingComponent);
  component = fixture.point.componentInstance;
  store = ngMocks.findInstance(MockStore);
  spinnerService = ngMocks.findInstance(NgxSpinnerService);
  testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
     expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
});

  fit('should take action on [loadProcessorsForGroupSuccess]', () => {
    const action = loadProcessorsForGroupSuccess({ processors: [] as any, gType: 'processing' });
    const spinnerSpy = jest.spyOn(spinnerService, 'show');

    store.dispatch(action);

  });
```

The test above is not fully flushed out, but when I dispatch the action `loadProcessorsForGroupSuccess` my component subscription never logs out anything.

How do I dispatch the subscribed to action so that my component will be triggered to subscribe to it and take the applicable action?

I have numerous other components that do something similar so I need a way to test this sort of action.

Comment: Your components shouldn't subscribe to actions, only reducers and effects should. You're struggling to build a unit test because your architecture isn't set up correctly. Your components should only subscribe to the store, and mocking store selectors is easy enough.

Comment: @WillAlexander Thanks for the quick response. So, if I understand correctly, I need to update my store (maybe like add a last updated field) and then have a selector that points to that. Then, whenever an update changes that field, my component can subscribe to the 'last updated' field and take appropriate action correct?

Comment: Exactly! You've got it. You can use a hash, for example, to represent the updated data. Whenever the hash changes, you know you have new data. Numbers representing datetimes also work.

Comment: @WillAlexander thanks... That's kinda what I figured. Unfortunately, my store is fairly large and I have a lot of specific actions I subscribe to in various components so welcome to 'refactorville' for me!

Comment: Best of luck with it!

Comment: You can create 2 effects showSpinner$ and hideSpinner$ and trigger them by the relevant actions. No need to put anything in a component at all. In fact the code you currently have looks very much like that of an effect minus the subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that everything is mocked (store and actions), this means that the `store.dispatch` method doesn't actually dispatch the action.
You can do `actions$.next(action)`, this way the `actions$` stream emits the dispatched action.